# <p> and <div> order when web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having difficulty scraping a web page that embeds `<div>` tags within `<p>` tags. When I find a div the output ends with the next `</p>` instead of continuing to `</div>`. And the output seems to have converted the `</p>` from the source code to a . I have tried using other inclusive `div` tags but my output always ends before the desired text.

HTML source code

```
<p><div class="asdf">Text</p>
<p>More Text</p></div>
```

Python code

```
print(soup.find(class_="asdf"))
```

Output

```
output = <div class="asdf">Text</div>
```

Desired output

```
<div class="asdf">Text</p><p>More Text</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the default parser (Python's built-in `html.parser`) which is not very good with malformed HTML code:

```
>>> BeautifulSoup("<div>Foo</p>Bar</div>", "html.parser").find("div")
<div>Foo</div>
```

Try installing `lxml` or `html5lib` and use that instead:

```
pip install html5lib
```

then:

```
>>> BeautifulSoup("<div>Foo</p>Bar</div>", "html5lib").find("div")
<div>Foo<p></p>Bar</div>
```

Read more about different parsers in [the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)